# MAC Validation Error Using Python Requests Posing a Form to ASP

Tags: python, asp.net, http, python-requests

[got Validation of viewstate MAC failed when sending post request from google app engine via url fetch service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316329/got-validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-when-sending-post-request-from-google-app)

Hello, I encountered the same problem as this post, I am posting a form to an ASP.NET hosted website, to replace Selenium

1. I used requests.Session()
2. Used session.get() to extract viewstate, eventvalidation, viewstategenerator and attached to my form
3. There's no other requests between my get and post, the viewstate rremain unchanged
4. cookies and header changed slightly with the session
5. I can post the form by Chrome, with JavaScript swithced off

```
def get_asp_viewstate(page):
    return {
    '__EVENTTARGET': '',
    '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
    '__LASTFOCUS': '',
    "__VIEWSTATE":page.xpath('//*[@id="__VIEWSTATE"]//@value')[0],
    "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR": page.xpath('//*[@id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"]//@value')[0], 
    "__EVENTVALIDATION": page.xpath('//*[@id="__EVENTVALIDATION"]//@value')[0],
    '__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED': '', #not encrypted
    }


def login():
    #login and return session object
    s = requests.Session()
    res = s.get(login_url)
    r = s.post(login_url, data=login_data, headers=headers)
    return s

#Had logged in 
session = login()

res = session.get(URL, cookies=session.cookies.get_dict())
page = etree.HTML(res.text)
validation = get_asp_viewstate(page)

form_data = {} # some dict
form_data.update(validation)

response = session.post(URL, headers=headers, cookies=cookie3,
 data=form_data, verify=False,allow_redirects=True)
```

I got http 500 for 100% try.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2915218/resolving-view-state-message-authentication-code-mac-errors

This page listed some cause, I am sure the app is not in multi-server environment, since the chance is 100%, not occasionally.

I think I am nearly out of ideas. 
Any help or suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Does cookie3 overwrite the session?

Comment: @waynelpu No, and I still get stucked.